# I can't find the superset-ui folder on Superset folder

Tags: apache-superset

I have install correctly the Apache Superset on my machine. My problem is that I can;t find the folder superset-ui or superset front-end to customize my charts. I see only .py files.

Has anyone an idea about this? I'm new in superset and generally in programming.
I have found that I need to install superset-ui through npm. Should I need to put this github file into superset file into my machine?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the installation using docker? All UI related views can be found in superset-frontend directory
See the screenshot below of my installed superset directory structure.
[image]

Let me know if this helps.